Extending $p$-adic smooth and locally constant functions
Let $G$ be $p$-adic group and let $G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation. For example, $V$ is a quadratic $\mathbb{Q}_p$-space and $G$ is the associated orthogonal group.
Take a point $v \in V$, let $H \subset G$ be its stabilizer and assume $X = H \backslash G = G \cdot v \subset V$ is a closed subvariety. To continue with the example, $H = O(v^{\perp})$.
I consider the indicator function of (the image via the projection $G \rightarrow H \backslash G$ of) $H \cdot K$, for some compact open subgroup $K$, and I want to extend this indicator function to a locally constant smooth function on $V$.
Is it somehow possible ? Do you know of any work that addresses similar questions ?

It's a bit unclear to me when you are working with rational points, and when not.  For example, do you want to regard $X$ as $G(\mathbb Q_p)\cdot v$ or $(G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p)$, which can be larger?  Is your $p$-adic field always of characteristic $0$, or might it be, say, $\mathbb F_p((t))$?  But, most importantly, regardless of these subtleties, I don't understand the question: by almost any interpretation, $H\backslash H\cdot K$ is compact open in the analytic topology, so its indicator is already locally constant (which, to me, in this context is what smooth means).  What is missing?

Yes sorry I am working with fields of characteristic $0$ and I meant $(G \cdot v)(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. I'm looking for a locally constant and smooth function $f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ whose restriction to $G \cdot v$ (which may be viewed as a function on $H \backslash G$) is the indicator function of $H \backslash H \cdot K$.

Since $H^1(\mathbb Q_p, H)$ is finite and each fibre of $(G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p) \to H^1(\mathbb Q_p, H)$ is closed, we have that the fibre $G(\mathbb Q_p)\cdot v$ over the trivial cohomology class is open (as well as closed).  Therefore, $G(\mathbb Q_p) \to (G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p)$ is an open map, so $K\cdot v$ is an analytically open subset of $(G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p)$.
Since $G\cdot v$ is a closed subvariety of $V$, we have that the analytic topology on $(G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p)$ is the subspace topology coming from the analytic topology on $V(\mathbb Q_p)$.  Thus $K\cdot v$ is of the form $U \cap (G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p)$ for some analytically open subset $U$ of $V(\mathbb Q_p)$.  Since the compact, open subsets of $V(\mathbb Q_p)$ form a basis for its topology, we can write $U$ as a union of compact, open subsets of $V(\mathbb Q_p)$.  Since $K\cdot v$ is compact, finitely many of these compact, open subsets of $V$ suffice to cover it.  Their union is compact, open, and still intersects $(G\cdot v)(\mathbb Q_p)$ in $K\cdot v$, so its indicator function is a smooth extension of the indicator function of $K\cdot v$.
